# how to mov 64 bit address to register

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I try to open file in assembly, to move value at memory locations(address) to rdi:

```
mov r13, [rsi+8*1] ; rsi - where addresses of cmdline parameters are.
mov [file_1], r13
; some calls...
mov rax, 2
mov rdi, [file_1] ; 
xor esi, esi ; automatically zero-extended to rsi
syscall
```

**SOLVED PROBLEM**:
   I determined length of the file but did not put seek position to beginning of the file like

```
mov rax, 8
mov rdi, [rsp+.fd_1]
xor esi, esi
mov edx, edx
syscall
```

Debugging:

```
(gdb) p/x &file_1
$1 = 0x601058
(gdb) x/xg 0x601058
0x601058: 0x00007fffffffe16a
(gdb) x/s 0x7fffffffe16a
0x7fffffffe16a: "abc"
```

but it does not move correctly. Also I read that `mov` has *32* bit source operand, but I need to move 64 bits from memory to register. Tried using movq in YASM, but it gave syntax error about invalid combination of opcode and operands.

Comment: What does this have to do with QuickTime?  `ESI` is 32-bit not 64-bit.  You should correct your assembly code to use the 64-bit register instead.  Why are you XOR'ing ESI with itself?  Based on the code you provided nothing is contained in ESI

Comment: changed, it was mistyping.

Comment: Your assembly code is still incorrect though.

Comment: @Ramhound, I would be very glad to make corrections, if you suggest one. Question was about `rdi`.

Comment: @BulatM. Print out the registers from gdb and show the outputs in your question.

Comment: @gowrath, tried to show relevant regesters in question, did i miss something? Problem Is that when I change 
it to
`segment .bss
abc db "abc", 0
; ... some code in between
mov rax, 2
lea rdi, [abc]  ; fixes the problem
xor esi, esi 
syscall`
Using the code in question I read 0 bytes from the file. Although I can determine that length is 25 bytes - file contains something, mysterious situation.

Comment: @Ramhound : xoring a value with itself yield a result of zero. `XOR ESI, ESI` sets ESI to zero and in 64-bit mode the CPU zero extends the 32-bit value across the upper 32-bits of the 64-bit register. In essence `XOR ESI,ESI` sets RSI to zero. RSI is the register that contains the `flags` for an open syscall. RDX should contain the `mode` and I don't see that in the code.

Comment: @PeterCorders, file_1 does not contain string, it contains address where string is located. Actually, it is a backup of an address of cmdline parameter. Please, check question.

Comment: I just did, that's why I reopened.  What does `but it does not move correctly.` mean?  What does `p /x $rdi` show, after executing `mov rdi, [file_1]`?

Comment: `Also I read that mov has 32 bit source operand`: maybe you're thinking of `mov reg, imm32`?  Otherwise that's totally wrong.  `movq` is AT&T syntax, so it's no surprise it doesn't assemble.  Anyway, YASM already uses `mov r64, imm64` if needed for large operands.

Comment: When I read from the file that I opened using open syscall passing filename in rdi, I read 0 bytes, however, file is not empty.
I need mode `mov r64, r64`. Does x64 architecture has it?

Comment: Your "solution" has nothing to do with the question you asked, or the title.  It's good to ask narrow specific questions, but asking about something that's working correctly wastes everyone's time even more.  This question has been terrible the whole time since it never showed `p /x $rdi` to confirm that what was loaded into RDI didn't match what was in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syscall 2 opens a file.

The parameters are:

```
rax: syscall #2
rdi: pointer: zero terminated filename
rsi: int: flags
rdx: int: mode
```

You use the following code:

```
...
mov rax, 2          //syscall_2 = open file
...
syscall
```

So far so good, however, according to the documentation:

> Given a pathname for a file, open() returns a file descriptor, a small, nonnegative integer for use in subsequent system calls.

So you've only done the first part, you hopefully gotten a **file descriptor**, with that you can **read data from the file**, you need to add that part to the code.
Finally when you're done you need to clean up after yourself and **close the file**.

Let me complete the code for you.

```
//********* get a file_descriptor.
push r15             //save non-volatile registers
push r14
mov eax,2            //syscall_2 = open file
mov rdi,[file_1]     //filename
xor esi,esi          //flags = O_RDONLY
xor edx,edx          //mode = 0, good habits: don't leave parameters undefined. 
syscall              //get me a file descriptor (fd).
test eax,eax         //is the fd positive?
mov edi,eax          //param1=fd
mov eax,1            //set failure code, just in case.
js failure           //no,it's negative,report failure.

//*********** read some data
//Step 2, we have a fd, lets read the data in the file.

mov r15,rax          //save the fd in a non-volatile register for later.
xor eax,eax          //syscall_0 = read data from file
mov rsi,[buffer]     //an array to place the data into
                     //`buffer` is the pointer to the buffer. 
mov edx,[len]        //the max_len of the buffer, must be >= 2.
dec edx              //keep an extra byte to put a zero terminator into.
//put 2 zero's if you're reading unicode_16 data.
syscall              //Read that data.
xor r14,r14          //assume a length of zero in case of failure.
                     //we can't jump to failure, we still need to clean up!
test eax,eax         //do we have a fail?
cmovs rax,r14        //if failure, then set zero length result, else do nothing.
mov [len],eax        //set len to the length of data read.
mov byte ptr [buffer+eax],0  //add a zero byte to terminate the data.

//************ clean up
//we are done, got the data. Let's close the file.

mov r14,rax          //if rax=0 then we had an error, store for later use
mov rdi,r15          //param1 = fd
mov eax,3            //syscall_3: close file
syscall              //close that file.
test eax,eax         //did close go ok?
mov eax,3            //set failure code just in case.
js failure           //negative = failure
//************ report back
//if we get here, all went ok, report success and return.
xor eax,eax          //return 0 for success.
//we still need to check if `read()` failed.   
sub r14,1            //carry = 1 only if r14 = 0 = failure else carry = 0
//sub eax,(0+carry)  //if success then no-op else eax=eax-1
sbc eax,eax          //eax = -1 if we had a failure when reading.
failure:
pop r14              //restore non-volatile registers
pop r15
ret                  //all done
```

**About 64 bits vs 32 bits**

> Also I read that mov has 32 bit source operand [...]

This is complete and utter hogwash.

X64 is a fully fledged 64 bit processor, that does what is says on the tin.
If you use a 64 bit register (any register that starts with an **`R`** (and doesn't end with a `d` or a `b`)) you use all 64 bits in that register.
Pointers to memory should **always** go into a 64bits `R` register.
If a register starts with an **`E`** (or ends with a `d`) it's a 32 bit register (the lower 32 bits).
*Any write operation on a 32 bits register zeros out the top 32 bits of the overlapped 64 bit register, e.g. `mov eax,1` sets `rax` to 1; `mov eax,-1` sets `rax` to `$0000 0000 FFFF FFFF`;*

`mov eax,2` and `mov rax,2` do the exact same thing.
Except that `mov eax,2` is two bytes shorter and is thus preferred.

If you read/write from/to memory the operation will follow the size of the register unless you specify otherwise.
If you write an immediate to memory you must specify the size.
You cannot write a 64-bit immediate to memory, you'll have to use 2 instructions to do that: `mov R64,imm64 + mov [mem],R64`.

**Caveat**
Any write to a 16-bits or 8-bits register does **not** zero out the top part of the associated 32/64 bits register!

**Conclusion**
If you want to write assembly, you need to actually learn assembly from the ground up.
Because you're programming in Linux I recommend getting a copy of Jeff Duntemann's book: [Assembly Language Step By Step, for Linux](http://www.duntemann.com/assembly.html)
Jeff is a legend and can explain assembly better than anyone on this planet.

Comment: `mov eax,2` is 2 bytes shorter.  `mov eax,2` is 5 bytes: opcode + imm32.  `mov rax, 2` uses the `REX mov r/m64, imm32` encoding, so it's 7 bytes including the ModR/M byte (which the 5 byte version doesn't have).  The REX version of the 5 byte encoding is the 10 byte `mov r64, imm64` (REX + opcode + imm64)

Comment: How did you figure out that the OP never called `read()`?  I tried to figure out this question, and it still doesn't show enough code to make sense.  Oh, maybe that's what their last comment actually meant.

Comment: @PeterCordes  I figured the code he's shown is all the code he has. It makes sense. To open a file in MS Word is to do everything that needs to be done with the file (full stop). It's just that syscall doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Johan, Thanks, got a few useful tips, actually problem was in not setting offset to beginning of the file, changed question, solved.

Answer (score 0):

> I determined length of the file but did not put seek position to beginning of the file

Did you find the length by reading to the end, leaving the file position at EOF?  Don't do that in the first place, use `fstat` to find the length of the file you've opened, if it has one.

It will have a length if it's a regular file or block device, and it won't if it's a pipe, socket, or tty (or other character device).  But the length could change before you finish reading it, if another process modifies it.

The only other way for the file position to point to the end is if you opened with `O_APPEND` in the flags.

---

Look at what system calls `strace cat infloop.c` uses (I've "commented out" and described the ones that aren't relevant if you're using a fixed-size static buffer; do something similar if you want)

```
open("infloop.c", O_RDONLY)             = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=29, ...}) = 0 # get the size
    # fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0
    # mmap(NULL, 139264, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ff78a7eb000    # allocate a buffer
read(3, "\nint main()\n{\n   while(1);\n}\n", 131072) = 29
write(1, "\nint main()\n{\n   while(1);\n}\n", 29) = 29
read(3, "", 131072)                     = 0           # read returning 0 means EOF
    # munmap(0x7ff78a7eb000, 139264)          = 0     # free the buffer
close(3)                                = 0
```

Comment: I determined length not by reading until the end of file and by counting characters-bytes in the process but by lseek, which immediatly sets the position after the end of the file and returns current length in `rax`.
lseek or fstat is preferred?

Comment: @BulatM.: You mean `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)`?  fstat is preferred over that, too, unless you *want* the current file position to change to the end of the file.  fstat also tells you whether you have a regular file, or terminal (e.g. if someone ran your program with `/dev/tty`), or whatever.  It's usually better just to check `read()`'s return value to detect EOF, instead of querying the length ahead of time.  Notice how the `strace cat` output does a 2nd `read` after it's already at the end of the file?

Comment: Thanks, I got the point, cat is encouraging, however, usage of lseek has some "advantage" of being coded faster both in C and assembly.

Comment: @BulatM.: What?   You mean faster to write? If you're looking for a language that's quick to write, assembly language is the wrong choice. The user-space side is trivial in complexity compared to the kernel code that executes when you call them.  If you use `lseek`, you have to call it twice, which is definitely going to be slower.

Comment: I did not think about it before, that way fstat(being called once) is definitely better.

Comment: @BulatM.: [This paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chensm/Big_Data_reading_group/papers/flexsc-osdi10.pdf) has some interesting data on system call overhead, and the cache misses / branch mispredictions suffered after a syscall returns (and inside the kernel during the syscall).  They have a neat design for a way to batch system calls from multiple thread together to reduce the direct and indirect overhead of all the context switching.